# Compiling cUrl with OpenSSL on Windows, missing -lcrypto and -lssl

Tags: windows, gcc, curl, openssl, libcrypto

When I try to compile cUrl without SSL support, there's no problem. I use command like this:

```
mingw32-make mingw32
```

I followed instructions in cUrl INSTALL file to make it support SSL, trying to compile it this way:

```
mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib OPENSSL_PATH=D:/Programy/MinGW/OpenSSL ZLIB_PATH=D:/Programy/MinGW/zlib
```

But it doesn't work as I get this error:

```
 D:\Programy\MinGW\cUrl>mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib OPENSSL_PATH=D:/Programy/Mi
nGW/OpenSSL ZLIB_PATH=D:/Programy/MinGW/zlib
mingw32-make -C lib -f Makefile.m32 CFG=mingw32-ssl-zlib
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Programy/MinGW/cUrl/lib'
gcc -s -shared -o libcurl.dll \
  -Wl,--output-def,libcurl.def,--out-implib,libcurldll.a \
  file.o timeval.o base64.o hostip.o progress.o formdata.o cookie.o http.o sendf
.o ftp.o url.o dict.o if2ip.o speedcheck.o ldap.o version.o getenv.o escape.o mp
rintf.o telnet.o netrc.o getinfo.o transfer.o strequal.o easy.o security.o curl_
fnmatch.o fileinfo.o ftplistparser.o wildcard.o krb5.o memdebug.o http_chunks.o
strtok.o connect.o llist.o hash.o multi.o content_encoding.o share.o http_digest
.o md4.o md5.o http_negotiate.o inet_pton.o strtoofft.o strerror.o amigaos.o hos
tasyn.o hostip4.o hostip6.o hostsyn.o inet_ntop.o parsedate.o select.o tftp.o sp
lay.o strdup.o socks.o ssh.o rawstr.o curl_addrinfo.o socks_gssapi.o socks_sspi.
o curl_sspi.o slist.o nonblock.o curl_memrchr.o imap.o pop3.o smtp.o pingpong.o
rtsp.o curl_threads.o warnless.o hmac.o curl_rtmp.o openldap.o curl_gethostname.
o gopher.o idn_win32.o http_negotiate_sspi.o http_proxy.o non-ascii.o asyn-ares.
o asyn-thread.o curl_gssapi.o curl_ntlm.o curl_ntlm_wb.o curl_ntlm_core.o curl_n
tlm_msgs.o curl_sasl.o curl_multibyte.o hostcheck.o bundles.o conncache.o pipeli
ne.o dotdot.o x509asn1.o http2.o curl_sasl_sspi.o smb.o curl_sasl_gssapi.o curl_
endian.o curl_des.o vtls/openssl.o vtls/gtls.o vtls/vtls.o vtls/nss.o vtls/polar
ssl.o vtls/polarssl_threadlock.o vtls/axtls.o vtls/cyassl.o vtls/schannel.o vtls
/darwinssl.o vtls/gskit.o libcurl.res -L"D:/Programy/MinGW/OpenSSL/lib" -lcrypto
 -lssl -L"D:/Programy/MinGW/zlib" -lz -lwldap32 -lws2_32
D:/Programy/MinGW/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x8
6_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcrypto
D:/Programy/MinGW/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x8
6_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.m32:300: recipe for target 'libcurl.dll' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [libcurl.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Programy/MinGW/cUrl/lib'
makefile:87: recipe for target 'mingw32-ssl-zlib' failed
mingw32-make: *** [mingw32-ssl-zlib] Error 2
```

I have downloaded cUrl v7.40.0 and Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2a from [Shining Light Productions](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). 
From what I understand, this distribution of OpenSSL contains `libeay32.dll`, `libssl32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` instead of `libcrypto.dll` and `libssl.dll` that I don't have and for for which the compiler is looking for. I also checked that I have all the three dlls in my `C:\Windows\System32` folder. I'm using MinGW-w64 compiler, no MSYS, version 4.9.2.

What do I need to do in order to compile cUrl library with SSL support on Win64? Do I need to modify my compile command, some file, or have I downloaded wrong version of OpenSSL to begin with? Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> ... Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2a from Shining Light Productions. From what I understand, this distribution of OpenSSL contains libeay32.dll, libssl32.dll and ssleay32.dll instead of libcrypto.dll and libssl.dll that I don't have and for for which the compiler is looking for.

OpenSSL should be available in the [MSYS Developer Tool Kit](http://www.mingw.org/node/48).

With the developer toolkit installed, just run:

```
mingw32-make mingw32-ssl-zlib
```

Mingw should find them since they are in well known locations without the need for `OPENSSL_PATH=D:/Programy/MinGW/OpenSSL`.

Just [bike shedding](http://bikeshed.com/): you should probably use `no-zlib` (or whatever the option is) since [compression can leak information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME).

Comment: I installed MSYS together with it's Developer Tool Kit and added it to my system environment path. When I try the command above without specifying `OPENSSL_PATH`, it get an error saying that it doesn't know the location of openssl, which is strange.