# Error: ld.exe: cannot find -lssl -lcrypto

Tags: c++, server, openssl

I am trying to run the code from this Website: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/01/26/openssl-part-3/
but i get the following error message

```
C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lssl -lcrypto
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I dont know what is the problem, since when i use

```
gcc -o client clientserv.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
```

to Compile other code it works fine but using the command from the website doesnt work.

Edit:
The command used on the website is

```
g++ -std=c++14 clientserv.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs openssl) -o https-server
```

Comment: what command do you use to compile ?

Comment: How are you running the code from the website?

Comment: what is "the command from the website" ? I didnt find it

Comment: @NathanOliver I am running the code locally

Comment: This command requires OpenSSL development libraries. Did you install the correct package for your Linux distribution?

Comment: Does `g++ -std=c++14 clientserv.cpp -lssl -lcrypto -o https-server` work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30027176/compiling-curl-with-openssl-on-windows-missing-lcrypto-and-lssl

Comment: It seems like people ignore that `gcc -o client clientserv.cpp -lssl -lcrypto` _"works fine"_. That would mean that the libraries are correctly installed.

Comment: What does `pkg-config --cflags --libs openssl` ouput?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I installed the correct Version of OPENSSL on my windows machine

Comment: @jabaa No, then i get alot of errors that there are undefined reference to 'std::allocator<char>::allocator()' for example

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `g++  test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs openssl) -o test` works just fine. The error message `cannot find -lssl -lcrypto` suggests that something is wrong with pkg-config. Normally each library that is not found is listed on its own line. Since the two are packed together in your case, it looks like there is some kind of invisible character between them that is NOT the ordinary ASCII space.

Answer (score -1):

So it seems that the proper command to run it on windows is

```
g++ -std=c++14 clientserv.cpp -lssl -lcrypto -o https-server
```

When using gcc instead it has some Problems, which led me to believe i have some configuration problem

Comment: See [What is the difference between g++ and gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)